# Does square difference prove that 1 = 2?

Tags: fake-proofs

I was mathematically shown 1 = 2 by a function that states the following

$$x^2-x^2 = x^2-x^2 $$
  $$x(x-x)=(x-x)(x+x)$$

dividing by $(x-x)$ we get...

$$x=x+x$$
    $$ x=2x$$
     $$1=2$$

I can see that mathematically he was right, but for sure that I was missing something as it doesn't make mathematical sense

Comment: Mathematically, it is wrong. $x-x=0$, and division by $0$ isn't allowed.

Comment: Cute, but invalid.

Comment: Remember that multiplying anything with zero is zero

Comment: Here's a shorter "fake proof:" $0\times1=0\times2$. Dividing out by $0$, we get $1=2$. This is essentially what your "proof" is doing, but your "proof" hides it more.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I don't see how OP's proof "hides it more"--this is one of the most abysmal fake proofs I have ever seen. Usually the flaw in dividing by zero is hidden somewhere and your goal is to track it down. Here it's just like, "Hey, divide by $x-x$," where it is *very* clear you are dividing by $0$.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow It hides it _slightly_ more, but the difference between the two proofs is smaller than $\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$ :P

Comment: I don't really understand why this question attracted so many downvotes. Yes, of course the answer is obvious to most of us, but aren't simple questions allowed? I don't think the question was asked in a poor way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this does not go unanswered...as others have mentioned, the *obvious* error is that you are dividing by $0$ by when you divide by $x-x$. Thus, whatever conclusion you reach is most certainly flawed.

The irksome thing in this case is that the flaw is hardly subtle. I would recommend you see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374950/what-is-wrong-with-this-proof-of-0-1) for a much more interesting attempt to fool readers into thinking $0=1$.

Answer (score 2):

0/0 is not equal to 1

You assumed it to be 1 when you divided by (x-x)

Answer (score 0):

When it shows x(x-x) it is not adding x to 0 it is multiplying.
In basic maths you learn that 5(7-2) is the same as 5 multiplied by (7-2)